# How to start Power BI Dataset refresh with SQL Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powerbi, sql-agent

In a certain requirement I have to start Power BI Dataset refresh only after SQL Agent job finished. My plan is to add a step in the Agent Job so that it can call the Power BI Data refresh. Any one has any idea how to achieve that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please review the following SO guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One step to do this is with with PowerShell. Install [Microsoft Power BI Management CmdLets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/power-bi/overview?view=powerbi-ps) and add a [PowerShell step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/run-windows-powershell-steps-in-sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-ver15) to execute the following script:

```
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile

$password = "xxxxx" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "xxxxx@yyyyy.com" 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'groups/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/datasets/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/refreshes' -Method Post

Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount
```

It will call the [Refresh Dataset In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdatasetingroup) REST API to initiate a dataset refresh.

Replace the x-es with the group/workspace ID and actual dataset ID. Also provide valid credentials. This is the simplest way, but you can also make it work with [service principal](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/use-power-bi-api-with-service-principal-preview/) for example.